# How to delete multiple rows in the gridview and into my database?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I want to delete multiple rows in my gridview by a button and at the same time it was deleted in the gridview, it will also be deleted into my database

I was able to try a code HERE:

THIS IS MY btn SAVE (it has INSERT and DELETE command)

```
 protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
        {

            if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {

                string RefNo = GridView1.DataKeys[row.RowIndex].Values[1].ToString();
                string ProductID = GridView1.Rows[row.RowIndex].Cells[1].Text;
                //string ProductID = GridView1.DataKeys[row.RowIndex].Values[1].ToString();
                string Name = GridView1.Rows[row.RowIndex].Cells[2].Text;
                decimal Price = decimal.Parse(GridView1.Rows[row.RowIndex].Cells[3].Text);
                int Quantity = int.Parse(GridView1.Rows[row.RowIndex].Cells[4].Text);
                int Amount = int.Parse(GridView1.Rows[row.RowIndex].Cells[5].Text);


                con.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
                cmd.Connection = con;
                cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO SODetails (SOID, ProductID, Name, Price, Quantity, Amount, RefNo) " +
                    "VALUES (@SOID, @ProductID, @Name, @Price, @Quantity, @Amount, @RefNo)";

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserID", Session["userid"].ToString());
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@SOID", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = SOID.Text;
                //cmd.Parameters.Add("@RefNo", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = RefNo;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@ProductID", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = ProductID.ToString();
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Name.ToString();
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Price", SqlDbType.Decimal).Value = Price;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Quantity", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Quantity;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Amount", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Amount;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@RefNo", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = RefNo;
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                //con.Close();

                //con.Open();

                cmd.CommandText = "DELETE FROM Orders";
                //cmd.Parameters.Add("@RefNo", RefNo);


                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
                GridView1.DataBind();

                con.Close();

            }
        }

    }
```

So honestly, IT DELETES BUT... just ONE RECORD

[Look here for my image of Gridview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c52U3.png)

Whenever i have 2 or more items in my gridview ERROR OCCURS SAYING:

```
Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.Parameter name: index

Line 245:                {
Line 246:
Line 247:                    string RefNo = GridView1.DataKeys[row.RowIndex].Values[1].ToString();
```

HERE IS MY ASP NET:

```
 <div class="col-lg-12" align="center">

&nbsp;<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
    DataKeyNames="RefNo" DataSourceID="SO" Width="1000px" Height="200px" 
       AllowPaging="True" HorizontalAlign="Center">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="RefNo" HeaderText="RefNo" InsertVisible="False" 
            ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="RefNo" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ProductID" HeaderText="ProductID" 
            SortExpression="ProductID" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="Name" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Price" HeaderText="Price" SortExpression="Price" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Quantity" HeaderText="Quantity" 
            SortExpression="Quantity" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Amount" HeaderText="Amount" 
            SortExpression="Amount" />
        <asp:ButtonField ButtonType="Button" CommandName="Delete" HeaderText="Delete" 
            ShowHeader="True" Text="Delete" />
    </Columns>
        <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />

</asp:GridView>

   <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SO" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:MyOwnMeatshopSO %>" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT Orders.RefNo, Orders.ProductID, Products.Name,     Orders.Price, Orders.Quantity, Orders.Amount FROM Orders INNER JOIN Products ON     Orders.ProductID = Products.ProductID">
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

```
   <div class="container">
   <div class="pull-right col-lg-5">
   <h4 />SUB TOTAL Php   <asp:Literal ID="ltSubTotal" runat="server">    </asp:Literal>
   <h4 />VAT (12%) 
   Php   <asp:Literal ID="ltVAT" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
   <h4 />TOTAL Php    <asp:Literal ID="ltTotal" runat="server"></asp:Literal>



   </div>
   </div>    
     <div class="container">    
<div class="pull-right col-lg-2">
    <asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" class="btn btn" Text="Save" 
    style="color:White" BackColor="Black" onclick="btnSave_Click"/>
   </div>

   </div>
```

The Error just occurs when i included the DELETE Command.
It looks like CAN'T DELETE MULTIPLE records from my GRIDVIEW & DATABASE.
AND looks like i have incomplete codes about it.

BUT again it deletes only one record and shows that error

Comment: Please compress your example to a datatable with one or two columns (ID, Data), remove the `INSERT` part, unless it is needed to reproduce the error.

Comment: @grek40 i am trying to delete it from the other data table from my database. -----

When save is clicked, the order is final (Inserts into new database).---

The delete needs to be done because it should be deleted from the cart (or the previous data table where the pre-final order had been saved).

Comment: Maybe you need to insert the order in your business logic. But users here on stackoverflow are not concerned about your business logic, but instead about your question/problem. So you should erase all parts from your question, that do not contribute to the actual problem at hand. Read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for more details

Comment: i know. i am just explaining it to you wondering if it's wht needed. i am just asking why the error occurs and that it just deletes one record at a time

Comment: Point is, I don't know (and neigher do others), so we have to spend time on your problem in order to figure it out. If you first spend the time to reduce your example, others might be willing to spend time helping you. However, if you just load a bulk of code and wait for others doing the work, you risk that no one will start spending time on it.